# What are the right signs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, conventions, lenses

This is a question provided in my book:

> An object of height $2\ \mathrm{cm}$ is placed at a distance of $2.5f$ from a concave mirror where $f$ is the focal length. Find the height of the image.

In the solution they took the object distance to be $-2.5f$ (which is correct) and they took the focal length $-f$.

Consider another simple numerical: You have a concave mirror, you know the object distance and the image distance, when you use the mirror formula, you never put focal length to equal $-f$. You just put a sign before $u$ and $v$, not with $f$.

So my question is, why have they put a negative sign on the focal length of the first numerical (I know that the focal length of a concave mirror is negative, but in other questions we don’t put the negative sign in front of focal length)?

Comment: Be careful!! Many books use a sign convention with f>0 for concave mirrors. There are a variety of sign conventions used for optics. When working problems, you have to determine which sign conventions the author is using.

Comment: @BillN , my book is using -f . But why isn’t it not using -f in other problems associated with concave mirrors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look back a few pages in the text book and see what version of the spherical mirror formula they use, and ***what the conventions are for the sign of various focal lengths, objects (real or virtual), and images (real or virtual)***.  These conventions are an integral part of the formula;  you will not be able to put data into the formula, or interpret the results, unless you use these rules.   Another textbook may have a very different looking formula, but with a different set of conventions, and will give the same answer as yours.

In this case, it is difficult to tell, but this is one possibility.  You say that the focal length for a concave mirror is negative.  But you want to place the **real** object at a **positive** distance that is four times the magnitude of the focal length.  So, you multiply the negative focal length by $4$ and then make it positive by chaging the sign.

Comment: My question is why have they used -f ?